# Tried to revert a commit now I'm diverged

Tags: git

Ok, I'm new to this so please be gentle.
I committed a file then I tried to revert it because it was wrong.  I used a tutorial on this site by using git `reset --soft HEAD~1`

Now it's saying my branch and the origin/master have diverged and have 2 and 13 different commit(s) each.  It lists some files that I had recently pulled after I originally did my commit.

Just FYI I never pushed the file, I just committed it.

Comment: I guess all I want to do is undo the changes on my machine and sync back up with the master.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Doing `git reset --hard origin/master` will do the trick.  But this will destroy all your changes.  If you get into this situation again and want to keep you commits, you have a couple of options.

1) `git pull`  This will merge the changes from origin/master into your local.  There will be a merge commit saying that you have "merge master into master".

2) `git pull --rebase`  This will rollback your commits to the last shared commit with origin/master.  Apply the changes that are on remote and finally apply your changes at the end.  This can result in conflicts but the history not have a merge commit in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just throw away your divergent commits, you can just `git reset --hard origin/master`.

Comment: This won't affect the master at all right?  Just my local box?  The reason I'm questioning is that I'm seeing changes by other users that have diverged, not just my own.

Comment: `master` *is* on your local box.  You can't affect the remote without doing `git push` if that's what you're asking.